# Add rows to a table in react jsx without duplicating row headings

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I want to pull data from firebase and then render it in my react component as a table. everything is working well so far and it renders the data correctly. However, I don't want to render the table headings every time. this is the code so far:

```
  <div className="table">
    <h1> Table </h1>
    {players.sort(function(a, b) {
          return (a.rank) - (b.rank);
      }).map(function(player, index) {
      index +=1;
      return <table>
              <tr>
                <th>Rank</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Wins</th>
                <th>Losses</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>{player.rank}</th>
                <th>{player.name}</th>
                <th>{player.wins}</th>
                <th>{player.losses}</th>
              </tr>
            </table>
    }, this)}
  </div>
```

I understand why it's doing it because every time I map over my array it returns my table headings. I cant quite work out a way to render the table headings differently. I want to move it out of this part but then I'm not sure how to link it up with the table if that makes sense. 
I basically just want `rank`, `name`, `wins`, `losses`, to be rendered once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just take the parts out of the map that you don't want to iterate with the data.

```
  <div className="table">
    <h1> Table </h1>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Rank</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Wins</th>
        <th>Losses</th>
      </tr>
    {players.sort(function(a, b) {
          return (a.rank) - (b.rank);
      }).map(function(player, index) {
      index +=1;
      return <tr>
               <th>{player.rank}</th>
               <th>{player.name}</th>
               <th>{player.wins}</th>
               <th>{player.losses}</th>
             </tr>
    }, this)}
     </table>
  </div>
```

Comment: but will this place it underneath in the correct place? like how will it know to sit under that table?